# -isator versus -isierer

Tags: suffix, word-formation

Zu Verben auf *-isieren* gibt es zwei Möglichkeiten, den Akteur dieser Handlung zu bezeichnen: mit *-isator* und *-isierer:*

- Stabilisator / Stabilisierer
- Homogenisator / Homogenisierer
- Magnetisator / Magnetisierer
- Visualisator / Visualisierer
- usw.

(1) **Warum** wird (2) **wann** welche Endung verwendet?

Comment: Vibrator - Vibrierer

Comment: @Emanuel Jo, und was will uns das sagen? Dass *-ator* die gebräuchlichere Endung ist? Dann googel mal *Magnetisator* (350 Treffer) und *Magnetisierer* (79100 Treffer). Beispielsweise. Außerdem frage ich nach *-isator*, und es heißt ja nicht "Vibrisator".

Comment: War nur als Scherz gemeint.

Comment: -(a)tor ist die lateinische Endung, -(r)er die deutsche. Von daher hängt es wahrscheinlich davon ab, ob das entsprechende Wort eher als Fremdwort oder als deutsches Wort gesehen wird, wann es in den allgemeinen Gebrauch gekommen ist, usw. Ich glaube nicht, dass es eine allgemeine Regel gibt.

Comment: Parallel zu -(a)tion und -(ier)ung. Motivation/Motivierung, Motivator/Motivierer. Aber Vorsicht: Konservation/Konservierung.

Comment: Nochmehr Vorsicht: Rasator/Rasierer ;)

Answer (score 4):

Erstmal denke ich, die Endungen sind *-ator/-itor* und *-(ier)er*. Im ersteren Fall wird aber mehr abgeschnitten, als im zweiteren Fall.

- stabilisieren -> stabilis -> stabilisator
- magnetisieren -> magnetisier -> magnetisierer

Insofern ist das Beispiel von Emanuel übrigens richtig und *Vibrisator* wäre inkorrekt.

*-ator* wird laut [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe-F/ator.html?MenuId=WordFormation110518) folgendermaßen verwendet:

> Die Ableitungen bezeichnen männliche Personen, die die Handlung des zugrunde liegende Verbs ausführen, sowie Geräte, Maschinen u. Ä., die die Verbhandlung ausführen oder zu deren Ausführung benutzt werden.

Selbiges gilt wohl auch für die Endung *-er*. So heißt es auf [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe/er.html?MenuId=WordFormation110426):

> Mit er von Verben abgeleitete Nomen bezeichnen regelmäßig Personen, die die durch das Verb ausgedrückte Tätigkeit ausüben. Es werden aber auch Nomen gebildet, die nicht Personen, sondern mit dem Verb verbundene Dinge oder Handlungen bezeichnen.

Daher gehe ich mit der Meinung von [dirkt](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15344/isator-versus-isierer/15345#comment36557_15344):

> Es [hängt] wahrscheinlich davon ab, ob das entsprechende Wort eher als Fremdwort oder als deutsches Wort gesehen wird, wann es in den allgemeinen Gebrauch gekommen ist, usw.

Comment: Die Duden Grammatik verzeichnet das Suffix als *-(at/it)or*.

Answer (score 3):

Man kann die Endungen auch noch etwas weiter auseinandernehmen:

Lateinische Infinitive enden auf *-re*, die häufigste Konjugationsklasse endet auf *-are*. Daher ist *-are* die Endung, um etwas zu einem Verb zu machen. (Beispiel: *navis* "Schiff" -> *navigare* "segeln"). Die entsprechende deutsche Endung ist *-ieren* (Beispiel: *edere* "herausgeben" -> ein Buch edieren; manchmal gibt es auch Varianten wie den Re-Import editieren "einen Text bearbeiten")

Für den Akteur ersetzt man im Lateinischen die Endung *-tum* des Partizip Passiv durch *-tor*. (Beispiele: *editor* "Herausgeber"; *navigator* "Schiffer, Matrose"). Substantive auf *-or* gehören zur konsonatischen Deklination. Die entsprechende deutsche Endung ist *-er* (backen -> Bäcker), und wenn das Verb mit *-ieren* gebildet wurde, eben *-ierer*.

Das anfängliche *-is-* kommt zumindest in den obigen Beispielen immer von der Endung *-is* für lateinische Adjektive. Das deutsche Equivalent ist *-ig*, *-ich*. Ein *-isierer* bzw. *-isator* ist also jemand oder etwas, der eine (ursprünglich lateinische) adjektivische Eigenschaft als Ziel einer Tätigkeit hat.

Die deutschen und lateinischen Endungen sind sich alle sehr ähnlich, sind also wahrscheinlich durch Lautverschiebung entstanden.

Wie gesagt sehe ich keine einfache Regel, die zwischen der lateinischen und der deutschen Endung entscheidet. Es hängt daher wohl von der Wortherkunftsgeschichte oder bei Neubildungen vom intendierten "Flair" ab.

Comment: Das ist mMn die richtige Antwort: "Robator" wäre nicht möglich, das heißt "Roboter" - Die Herkunft macht's. Und wahrscheinlich gibt es für Wörter lateinischer Herkunft mehr Ausnahmen als "konforme" Wörter.